# Parse: Updating array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to upload an array with the following code, but I am getting an error on the second to last line which says `Cannot assign to value: function call returns immutable array`

```
for object in objects! {
  let newstring = NSString(format: ".0f", self.slider.value)
  var newarray = [object.objectForKey("times")]
  newarray.append(newstring)
  object.objectForKey("times") = newarray
  object.saveInBackground()
}
```

"times" is of type array in parse by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than requesting the array and trying to set it you should be using `setObject:forKey:` to replace the existing value.

```
object.setObject(newarray, forKey: "times")
```

Comment: Oh ok, so just replace the second to last line with that

Comment: Just to clarify why you got the error object.objectForKey("times") is a function call that returns the value at key "times", being an immutable array. You then tried to assign a value to that immutable array. Which even if the array was mutable would not update the value of the array in the dictionary. This is why you need to use setObject() like this answer gives.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using the `addObject:forKey:` method instead?

```
for object in objects! {
  let newstring = NSString(format: ".0f", self.slider.value)
  object.addObject(newstring, forKey: "times")
  object.saveInBackground()
}
```

It is much cleaner and doesn't require retrieval :)